# UAA client CAS5 IDP OIDC Pac4j Session profile missing accessToken

Tags: java, cas, openid-connect

I am attempting to configure an UAA (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa) SSO server to use CAS5 as an IDP.

The call to 'cas/authorize' is succeeding. The callback URL is called to the UAA server. The UAA server is then trying to call 'cas/accessToken' during the serving of the 'callback' URL endpoint to the browser, i.e. back-end HTTP request is being made back to CAS5.

I have traced through the execution of the 'cas/accessToken' request within CAS5. The request is failing on the Pac4j Profile lookup. The profile is trying to be accessed via either the request object or the session object. For the previous call to 'cas/authorize' the lookup succeeds via the session but for the 'cas/accessToken' the session does not contain the profile because the request is originating from the UAA server backend and not the user's browser.

Is this a bug with the OIDC support in CAS5? How do I get the Pac4j Profile lookup to succeed here?

Here is the stack trace where the profile lookup fails within CAS5:
`ProfileManager<U>.retrieveAll(boolean) line: 69
ProfileManager<U>.get(boolean) line: 35
OAuth20AuthorizeEndpointController.isRequestAuthenticated(ProfileManager,J2EContext) line: 142
OidcAuthorizeEndpointController(OAuth20AuthorizeEndpointController).handleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 109    OidcAuthorizeEndpointController.handleRequest(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse) line: 86`

Comment: @MisaghMoayyed any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 5.1.0 not 5.2.2. I had rolledback to 5.1.0 around this time.

The problem still exists in the 5.1.0 code. I resolved by modified the OidcIdTokenGeneratorService to pull the CLAIM_PREFERRED_USERNAME from the TGT:

```
if (!claims.hasClaim(OidcConstants.CLAIM_PREFERRED_USERNAME)) {
    String username = accessTokenId.getGrantingTicket().getAuthentication().getCredentials().get(0).getId();
    claims.setClaim(OidcConstants.CLAIM_PREFERRED_USERNAME, username);
}
```

vs

```
if (!claims.hasClaim(OidcConstants.CLAIM_PREFERRED_USERNAME)) {
    claims.setClaim(OidcConstants.CLAIM_PREFERRED_USERNAME, profile.getId());
}
```

There were some other calls upstream in the OAuth20AccessTokenEndpointController to get the CLIENT_ID via pac4j. The CLIENT_ID is also available as a request param. Changed calls similar to:

```
final String clientId = uProfile.getId();
```

to

```
final String clientId = request.getParameter(OAuth20Constants.CLIENT_ID);
```